# Read Registry key and write in textbox the value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

I have found the following code which reads and writes from the registry.

```
// Write a value to the registry
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name","Isabella");

// Get value from registry
key.GetValue("Name");    
textBox1.Text = key.GetValue("Name"); // error, how can I do?

key.Close();
```

How would I display the value in a TextBox?

Comment: Can not implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. There is an explicit conversion. Probable missing cast

Comment: string value = key.GetValue("Name").ToString();

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a call `ToString()` after ensuring the value isn't null.

```
object oVal = key.GetValue("Name");
if (null != oVal) 
{
   textBox1.Text = oVal.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks man..sorry for the question but this is my first application

Answer (score 1):

try

```
textBox1.Text = key.GetValue("Name").ToString();
```

GetValue returns an object and textbox1.Text wants a string so you need to convert first.